# Custom TabBarItem menu IOS 7

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

I'm trying to make an UITabBarController like this:

[image]

No matter the device width (whether it is rotated or not) the buttons should not be stretched and the leftover space should be on the right side.

**My questions**:

1. Is this possible with the UITabBarController?
2. For the whitelines inbetween the buttons I am planning to use an unclickable UITabBarItem with an image. Is this the best way to do this?
3. With [this tutorial](http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/ios-custom-ui-series-tabbar-navbar/) that I followed I am getting this result:
   [image]

2 problems here ^, whilst my background.png is **320x49**, the selected image (**68x49**) has padding. This should not happen, both pictures have the same height?

The second problem is that the button/image has trailing space, and I want it sticked to the left side, as in my first screenshot. How would I accomplish this?

I don't expect anyone to post code, just merely a push in the right direction as I'm totally lost on this.

Comment: Check this [library](https://github.com/mhaddl/MHCustomTabBarController), you can customize the ui with constraints and get what you want.

Comment: Being able to use UI items with constrains was exactly what I needed, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [library](https://github.com/mhaddl/MHCustomTabBarController), you can customize the UI in interface builder with consstraints and get what you want.